# embedding videos loaded on box

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, box-api

So basically we would like to integrate our platform with box.net, in particular to be able to stream videos uploaded there, since we can't unfortunately use youtube/vimeo (which support noembed).

I had a look in the doc and:

- it seems that for videos the preview is only working for flv and swf.
  However I tried with my personal account and one swf embedded with their embedding link didn't preview anyway.
- I would like to use the API to upload videos directly from the client, but what happens if the user is not actually authenticated to box.net and the video is private (which is our requirement).

If embedding videos with box is just not going to work we can look at other alternatives, but unfortunately from the list of supported sites http://noembed.com/
it doesn't that we could use any of the services..

Comment: For your first point, Box does support more file types for videos, but requires an enterprise account to do so: https://support.box.com/entries/20366111-What-file-extension-types-can-be-accessed-by-Box-s-Content-Preview-

Answer (score 2):

For the second point, you can just do all the authentication for your site via box.net. They provide authentication as part of their api: http://developers.box.com/oauth/.

When a user logs into your site, authenticate them with box.net using python [`requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/), and a custom authentication backend, django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend), example on stack overflow here: [Django Remote Authentication without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896703/django-remote-authentication-without-redirecting/19934580#19934580).